# When your key independent variable is a difference between x1 and x2, do you control for x1 and x2?

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to estimate the effect of difference in ranks between two people (i and j) on an outcome Y using a linear regression. My independent variable of interest is the $\beta$ coefficient on $(Rank_i - Rank_j)$. Should I include fixed effects for $Rank_i$ *and* $Rank_j$, or just one of them? Assignment of $Rank_i$ to $Rank_j$ in this setting is quasi-exogenous. Importantly, $Rank_i$ and $Rank_j$ have their own directs effects on Y, which is why I want to control for both. However, that feels wrong? How can you hold $Rank_i$ and $Rank_j$ constant, while estimating $\beta$?

Including them both doesn't really change estimates on the difference much (compared to when only one fixed effect is included), just makes it noisier. I just want to do the right thing, and include a reference to explain why I made the decision I did.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First, I'm not sure how the independent variable can be $\beta$ for the difference. Maybe you mean the actual difference?   Second, if you include two variables and their difference, you will have perfect coliniarity and the model will not be estimable.

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes, apologies. This is my first post here. I meant the independent variable is literally the difference between Rank_i and Rank_j. I thought it would be collinear too, but somehow it is still being estimated by the program. Which confuses me. What if my independent variable of interest is an indicator for whether (Rank_i > Rank_j)? Could I then include fixed effects for Rank_i and Rank_j and still be able to interpret the coefficient on the indicator? If it helps, Rank_i and Rank_j have 28 different values.

Comment: @PeterFlom I should add that Rank_i and Rank_j are treated as categorical, not continuous.

Comment: If you are treating them as categorical, how are you finding a difference? ("Ranks" don't fall neatly into the hierarchy of "nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio")'

Comment: @PeterFlom In this case I'm talking about 2 peoples' rank in an organization. So a rank 3 (mid-level manager) individual has an encounter with a rank 7 individual (executive). The difference between them would be 4, for example. So I guess they would be ordinal. Hence the fixed effects for rank.